# Appending a row of sums for each level of a factor

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

I want to append a row of sums for each Reg like this

```
   Reg   Res    Pop
1      Total 1000915
2    A Urban 500414
3    A Rural 500501

4     Total  999938
5    B Urban 499922
6    B Rural 500016

7      Total 1000912
8    C Urban 501638
9    C Rural 499274

10     Total  999629
11    D Urban 499804
12    D Rural 499825

13     Total 1000303
14   E Urban 499917
15   E Rural 500386
```

MWE is below:

```
Reg <- rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 2)
Res <- rep(c("Urban", "Rural"), times = 5)
set.seed(12345)
Pop <- rpois(n = 10, lambda = 500000)
df <- data.frame(Reg, Res, Pop)

df
   Reg   Res    Pop
1    A Urban 500414
2    A Rural 500501
3    B Urban 499922
4    B Rural 500016
5    C Urban 501638
6    C Rural 499274
7    D Urban 499804
8    D Rural 499825
9    E Urban 499917
10   E Rural 500386

df %>%
   group_by(Reg) %>%
   summarise(Total = sum(Pop))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     Reg   Total
  <fctr>   <int>
1      A 1000915
2      B  999938
3      C 1000912
4      D  999629
5      E 1000303
```

**Edited**

I would like to have both `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an extra *Res* column to the summary and then `bind_rows` with the original data frame:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Reg) %>%
    summarise(Pop = sum(Pop), Res = 'Total') %>%
    bind_rows(df) %>% 
    arrange(Reg)

# A tibble: 15 x 3
#     Reg     Pop   Res
#   <chr>   <int> <chr>
# 1     A 1000915 Total
# 2     A  500414 Urban
# 3     A  500501 Rural
# 4     B  999938 Total
# 5     B  499922 Urban
# 6     B  500016 Rural
# 7     C 1000912 Total
# 8     C  501638 Urban
# 9     C  499274 Rural
#10     D  999629 Total
#11     D  499804 Urban
#12     D  499825 Rural
#13     E 1000303 Total
#14     E  499917 Urban
#15     E  500386 Rural
```

---

A corresponding `data.table` solution:

```
dt <- setDT(df)
rbindlist(list(dt[, .(Pop = sum(Pop), Res = 'Total'), Reg], dt), use.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lapply(split(df, df$Reg),
       function(a) rbind(data.frame(Reg = a$Reg[1],
                                    Res = "Total",
                                    Pop = sum(a$Pop)),
                         a))
$A
  Reg   Res     Pop
1   A Total 1000915
2   A Urban  500414
3   A Rural  500501

$B
  Reg   Res    Pop
1   B Total 999938
3   B Urban 499922
4   B Rural 500016

$C
  Reg   Res     Pop
1   C Total 1000912
5   C Urban  501638
6   C Rural  499274

$D
  Reg   Res    Pop
1   D Total 999629
7   D Urban 499804
8   D Rural 499825

$E
   Reg   Res     Pop
1    E Total 1000303
9    E Urban  499917
10   E Rural  500386
```

You could convert the whole thing to data.frame by using `do.call(rbind, ...)` if you want

Answer (score 1):

Stacking and rearranging will work:

```
library(dplyr)

Reg <- rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 2)
Res <- rep(c("Urban", "Rural"), times = 5)
set.seed(12345)
Pop <- rpois(n = 10, lambda = 500000)
df <- data.frame(Reg, Res, Pop, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


sums <- df %>%
  group_by(Reg) %>%
  summarise(Pop = sum(Pop)) %>%
  mutate(Res = "Total")

df_sums <- bind_rows(df, sums) %>% 
  arrange(Reg, Res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data:

```
Reg <- rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 2)
Res <- rep(c("Urban", "Rural"), times = 5)
set.seed(12345)
Pop <- rpois(n = 10, lambda = 500000)
df  <- data.frame(Reg, Res, Pop)

require(dplyr)
df1 <- 
df %>%
  group_by(Reg) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Pop))
```

My solution (note: I also send the earlier pipe to `df1`):

```
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(Reg=df1$Reg, Res="Total", Pop=df1$Total))

df <- df[order(as.character(df$Reg), decreasing = T),]
df <- df[seq(dim(df)[1],1),]
```

Result:

```
print(df, row.names = F)
```

> ```
>  Reg   Res     Pop
>    A Total 1000915
>    A Rural  500501
>    A Urban  500414
>    B Total  999938
>    B Rural  500016
>    B Urban  499922
>    C Total 1000912
>    C Rural  499274
>    C Urban  501638
>    D Total  999629
>    D Rural  499825
>    D Urban  499804
>    E Total 1000303
>    E Rural  500386
>    E Urban  499917
> ```

If you want to print them with line breaks in between the groups, without changing the data types:

```
for(g in unique(df$Reg)){
  print(df[df$Reg==g,], row.names = F)
  cat("\n")
}
```

> ```
>  Reg   Res     Pop
>    A Total 1000915
>    A Rural  500501
>    A Urban  500414
>
>  Reg   Res    Pop
>    B Total 999938
>    B Rural 500016
>    B Urban 499922
>
>  Reg   Res     Pop
>    C Total 1000912
>    C Rural  499274
>    C Urban  501638
>
>  Reg   Res    Pop
>    D Total 999629
>    D Rural 499825
>    D Urban 499804
>
>  Reg   Res     Pop
>    E Total 1000303
>    E Rural  500386
>    E Urban  499917
> ```

You also requested a **data.table** solution. This is identical to what's above, except create `df1` like this:

```
dt  <- as.data.table(df)
df1 <- dt[,sum(Pop),by=dt$Reg]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` and `purrr`. This is similar to d.b's method, but the output of `map_dfr` would be a data frame. So no further conversion from list to data frame is needed. Notice that I used the `data_frame` function to construct the `df` because for this analysis factor is not needed. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data_frame(Reg, Res, Pop)

df2 <- df %>%
  split(.$Reg) %>%
  map_dfr(~bind_rows(.x, data_frame(Reg = .x$Reg[1], Res = "Total", Pop = sum(.x$Pop))))

df2 
# A tibble: 15 x 3
     Reg   Res     Pop
   <chr> <chr>   <int>
 1     A Urban  500414
 2     A Rural  500501
 3     A Total 1000915
 4     B Urban  499922
 5     B Rural  500016
 6     B Total  999938
 7     C Urban  501638
 8     C Rural  499274
 9     C Total 1000912
10     D Urban  499804
11     D Rural  499825
12     D Total  999629
13     E Urban  499917
14     E Rural  500386
15     E Total 1000303
```

Comment: Fwiw, I like d.b's answer *because it is in a list* and therefore easier on the eyes. I can't imagine any good use-case for a "margin" computation (like total here) except for browsing. I'm guessing purrr has some simple way of mimicking his answer / giving a list instead of a tibbeldy-do.

Comment: @Frank List does look good. I proposed this answer because the desired output from OP looks like a data frame. If you want a list, change `map_dfr` to `map`.

Answer (score 1):

The development version 1.10.5 of the `data.table` package (see [here for installation instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)) has three new functions for calculating aggregates at various levels of groupings which can be used here.

Note that OP's expected result contains contiguous row numbers 1 to 15 which suggest that the OP is expecting one data.frame or data.table rather than a list as preferred by [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122047/appending-a-row-of-sums-for-each-level-of-a-factor/46122122#comment79208094_46122346). However, we will show below that also a data.table can be printed in an eye-friendly way.

#### `rollup()`

With the new `rollup()` function and ordering by `Reg`

```
library(data.table)   # development version 1.10.5 as of 2015-09-10
setDT(df)
rollup(df, j = list(Pop = sum(Pop)), by = c("Reg", "Res"))[order(Reg)]
```

we do get

> ```
>     Reg   Res     Pop
>  1:   A Urban  500414
>  2:   A Rural  500501
>  3:   A    NA 1000915
>  4:   B Urban  499922
>  5:   B Rural  500016
>  6:   B    NA  999938
>  7:   C Urban  501638
>  8:   C Rural  499274
>  9:   C    NA 1000912
> 10:   D Urban  499804
> 11:   D Rural  499825
> 12:   D    NA  999629
> 13:   E Urban  499917
> 14:   E Rural  500386
> 15:   E    NA 1000303
> 16:  NA    NA 5001697
> ```

The respective totals are indicated by `NA` (including a grand total). If we want to better reproduce the expected result, the grand total can be removed and `NA` be replaced by `Total`:

```
rollup(df, j = list(Pop = sum(Pop)), by = c("Reg", "Res"))[order(Reg)][
  is.na(Res), Res := "Total"][!is.na(Reg)]
```

> ```
>     Reg   Res     Pop
>  1:   A Urban  500414
>  2:   A Rural  500501
>  3:   A Total 1000915
>  4:   B Urban  499922
>  5:   B Rural  500016
>  6:   B Total  999938
>  7:   C Urban  501638
>  8:   C Rural  499274
>  9:   C Total 1000912
> 10:   D Urban  499804
> 11:   D Rural  499825
> 12:   D Total  999629
> 13:   E Urban  499917
> 14:   E Rural  500386
> 15:   E Total 1000303
> ```

Note that the `Total` rows appear *below* the details rows which isn't fully in line with OP's expected result.

#### `groupingsets()`

With the `groupingsets()` function, the aggregations can be controlled in great detail:

```
groupingsets(df, j = list(Pop = sum(Pop)), by = c("Reg", "Res"), 
             sets = list("Reg", c("Reg", "Res")))[order(Reg)][
               is.na(Res), Res := "Total"][]
```

> ```
>     Reg   Res     Pop
>  1:   A Total 1000915
>  2:   A Urban  500414
>  3:   A Rural  500501
>  4:   B Total  999938
>  5:   B Urban  499922
>  6:   B Rural  500016
>  7:   C Total 1000912
>  8:   C Urban  501638
>  9:   C Rural  499274
> 10:   D Total  999629
> 11:   D Urban  499804
> 12:   D Rural  499825
> 13:   E Total 1000303
> 14:   E Urban  499917
> 15:   E Rural  500386
> ```

Now, the `Total` rows appear above the details rows and no grand total was created at all.

#### Nicely printed  "classic" `data.table` solutions

Up to now, two "classic" `data.table` solutions were posted by [Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46122132/3817004) and [Hack-R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46122227/3817004).

Both could be re-written more concisely as

```
rbind(df[, .(Res = "Total", Pop = sum(Pop)), by = Reg], df)[order(Reg)]
```

The result can be printed in an "eye-friendly" way with blank lines between the groups using

```
rbind(df[, .(Res = "Total", Pop = sum(Pop)), by = Reg], df)[
  order(Reg), {print(data.table(Reg, .SD), row.names = FALSE); cat("\n")}, by = Reg]
```

> ```
>  Reg   Res     Pop
>    A Total 1000915
>    A Urban  500414
>    A Rural  500501
>
>  Reg   Res    Pop
>    B Total 999938
>    B Urban 499922
>    B Rural 500016
>
>  Reg   Res     Pop
>    C Total 1000912
>    C Urban  501638
>    C Rural  499274
>
>  Reg   Res    Pop
>    D Total 999629
>    D Urban 499804
>    D Rural 499825
>
>  Reg   Res     Pop
>    E Total 1000303
>    E Urban  499917
>    E Rural  500386
> ```